# Ordering wordpress posts by meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I have done a lot of research, followed suggestions and ended up with the following query:

```
$query = array(
     'posts_per_page' => (int) $count,
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'meta_key' => '_kjl_fb_likes',
     'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
     'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

But post are just not ordered by the number of likes.

Meta date is checked and it is saved with every post.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Your code should work, have you tried `meta_value` instead of `meta_value_num`

Comment: yes, I did, with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to cast meta type as unsigned integer, try this:

```
$query = array(
 'posts_per_page' => (int) $count,
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'meta_key' => '_kjl_fb_likes',
 'meta_type' => 'UNSIGNED', 
 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
 'order' => 'DESC'
);
```